# What are the available value(s) for "seed for Randome Function" used in JMeter for Random Variable config Element

Tags: random, element, jmeter, config, seed

Need to know what are the available value(s) for "seed for Random Function" used in JMeter for Random Variable config Element.
(It would be better with examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A seed is a value used to generate random output on. As a random number function is really just a function, the "random" value being output is always based on the seed. In other words, if you seed the random output generator with the same seed value, you will get the same "random" result. This is why most random number generators use the system time to seed themselves, as that is highly variable.

Now back to your question. If you specify a seed, you will get fixed random output. This makes it easy for you to repeat the test with the exact same random values, just pass in the same seed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Erick. 
Can you let me know, what are the available seeds that i can use for the "seed for Random Function" in JMeter. 

Cz in Jmeter documentation says "The seed for the random number generator. Default is the current time in milliseconds. If you use the same seed value with Per Thread set to true, you will get the same value for earch Thread as per Random class." Bit confusing for me.

Need to know what are the values i can use to put to this field. :)

Comment: Any idea on values(s) can use for seeds?

Comment: Depends on what you want. Do you want the values to be different each time, then you need to leave it empty (it will then use the [current time in milliseconds](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Variable)). If you want it to generate the same "random" values each time you call it, you give it fixed numeric value.